# Blender's window opens at roughly 1.5 my monitor size

Tags: interface

When I open my Blender, its window seems is roughly 1.5 the size of my monitor. I recently just updated to 4.0.1. Prior to the update, this issue never occurred. When I minimize the window and then maximize it, everything appears fine (as in the second image). This is a workaround. How can I fix this permanently?

[image: A screenshot of a just opened blender window]

[image: A screenshot of how it should look]

Comment: What operating system are you using? - It looks as if Blender's main window has been zoomed larger than your monitor size. I'd suggest that you start Blender, minimise it and maximise as you've said to get the normal size then use File > Defaults > Save Startup File and see if that sorts it.

Comment: i tried that it doesnt fix it, my operating system is ubuntu

Comment: Don't know about Linux, but in Windows the window size, state and location is stored by the operating system (in the registry under Windows) when you close a program. If ubuntu is the same I doubt it's anything to do with Blender itself.